# Не получается handshake с пиром. BitTorent

Tags: python-3.6, torrent

Вот мой код:

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((peer_id, peer_port))

message = b'\x13BitTorrent protocol\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' + bytes('1A6948C96FA8302C74DA680C7360D1486A52B2F9'.lower(), encoding="UTF8") + b'66788486352714431784'

sock.send(message)

print('s')

while True:
    try:
        resp = sock.recv(len(message))
        print(resp)
        if resp != b'':
            break
    except:
        pass
```

В ответ от пира я получаю пустую строку b''. Причём эта строка постоянно печатается в консоле

В чём проблема?

Comment: После небольшого исследования выяснил, что некоторые пиры могут вообще не возвращать ответа из-за большой нагрузки (https://translatedby.com/you/bittorrent-protocol-specification-v1-0-in-detail/into-ru/trans/?page=13), возможно из-за этого я получаю пустой ответ, а не разрыв соединения.

Comment: Пустой ответ как раз и обозначает разрыв соединения

Comment: Тогда почему я получаю его постоянно?

Answer (score 0):

В строке 7 info_hash нужно закодировать в байты вот так:
hashlib.sha1(torrent_file['info']).digest()

А в своём коде я использовал метод hexdigest. Конечный код выглядит так:

```
import hashlib
import bencode
import random
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((peer_ip, peer_host))

torrent_file = bencode.decode(open('test.torrent', 'rb').read())
info_hash_raw = hashlib.sha1(bencode.bencode(torrent_file['info'])).digest()


message = b'\x13BitTorrent protocol\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x05' + info_hash_raw + bytes(str(random.randint(10**20, 10**21-1)), encoding="UTF-8")

sock.send(message)

while True:
  try:
    resp = sock.recv(len(message))
    print(resp)
    break
  except:
    pass
```